# Range sensor plug-in for gazebo not loading

Tags: gazebo-plugin, ros-noetic, sensor

I am trying to implement an ultrasonic sensor to the front of my differential drive robot. I followed the gazebo tutorial, but when I launch my file the plug-in does not seem to load correctly. The URDF file was automatically generated. I want to add an ultrasonic sensor to the link "sensor_front". Compiles and returns no errors.

this is the relevant part of the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- This URDF was automatically created by SolidWorks to URDF Exporter! Originally created by Stephen Brawner (brawner@gmail.com) 
     Commit Version: 1.6.0-4-g7f85cfe  Build Version: 1.6.7995.38578
     For more information, please see http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter -->
<robot name="robot_model1">
  <link
    name="base_link"> 
<!-- more link info... -->

<!-- ULTRASONIC SENSOR FRONT -->

  <link
    name="sensor_front">
    <inertial>
      <origin
        xyz="-0.0121627640002075 0.000315813672030385 0.0111068141744769"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass
        value="0.013088886409699" />
      <inertia
        ixx="3.78061866294621E-06"
        ixy="1.73366653344102E-09"
        ixz="2.49429010509448E-07"
        iyy="1.47205044255623E-06"
        iyz="-7.66343233303314E-11"
        izz="2.96204702847941E-06" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_model1/meshes/sensor_front.STL" />
      </geometry>
      <material
        name="">
        <color
          rgba="0.752941176470588 0.752941176470588 0.752941176470588 1" />
      </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
      <origin
        xyz="0 0 0"
        rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh
          filename="package://robot_model1/meshes/sensor_front.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>

 <!-- ULTRASONIC SENSOR Plugin NOT LOADING... -->
<gazebo>

    <sensor type="ray" name="sonar">
      <pose>0.25 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <update_rate>10</update_rate>
      <ray>
        <scan>
          <horizontal>
           <samples>5</samples>
           <resolution>1.0</resolution>
           <min_angle>-0.25</min_angle>
           <max_angle>0.25</max_angle>
          </horizontal>
          <vertical>
            <samples>5</samples>
            <resolution>1</resolution>
            <min_angle>-0.25</min_angle>
            <max_angle>0.25</max_angle>
          </vertical>
        </scan>
        <range>
          <min>0.01</min>
          <max>0.75</max>
          <resolution>0.01</resolution>
        </range>
      </ray>
      <plugin filename="libgazebo_ros_range.so" name="gazebo_ros_range">
            <gaussianNoise>0.005</gaussianNoise>
            <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
            <updateRate>5</updateRate>
            <topicName>sonar</topicName>
            <frameName>sonar_link</frameName>
            <fov>0.5</fov>
            <radiation>ultrasound</radiation>
      </plugin>
    </sensor>
</gazebo> 

<!-- more link info... -->

<robot/>
```